# How to write 1 byte to a binary file?

Tags: python, filehandle

I'm trying to write just one byte to a file in Python.

```
i = 10
fh.write( six.int2byte(i) )
```

Will output '0x00 0x0a'

```
fh.write( struct.pack('i', i) )
```

Will output '0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x00'

I want to write a single byte with the value 10 to the file.

Comment: How did you open `fh`?

Comment: Are you talking about [file-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), [file-descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations) or actual [file handles on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364225(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: You should add code on how it was opened. DId you open with with regular `open` or something else? What is its type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just build a `bytes` object with that value:

```
with open('my_file', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes([10]))
```

This works only in python3. If you replace `bytes` with `bytearray` it works in both python2 and 3.

Also: remember to open the file in binary mode to write bytes to it.

Comment: in python2.7 this generates: 0x31 0x5b 0x3d 0x30.  with bytearray it generates 0x00 0x0a

Comment: I take it back - I was using hexdump -x to look at the file which was padding the extra 0x00.  The bytearray works.

Comment: bytes/bytearray take values from 0 to 255 (unsigned) - so don't put in negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

`struct.pack("=b",i)` (signed) and `struct.pack("=B",i)` (unsigned) pack an integer as a single byte which you can see in the [docs for struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters). (`"="` is for using standard size and ignoring alignment - just in case) so you can do

```
import struct
i=10
with open('binfile', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(struct.pack("=B",i))
```

Comment: this also generates 0x00 0x0a (wither either =b or =B option)

Comment: @reza - just tried this, on MSYS2 python2 and python3, and I get a file which is exactly 1 byte in size; with just 0x0a as content, when viewed either with `dhex` or with `hexdump -C binfile`

Answer (score 0):

```
i=10
f=open('binfile', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(chr(i))
f.close()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is over five years old) with existing and accepted answers.

Comment: Furthermore it must be `f.close()`, but in general the use as context manager is recommended anyway.

Comment: ok smarty, I forgot the ( ). You really make people welcome. I don't care if it's accepted old or what. I just posted another (and simpler) way to do it. Oh and you didn't even notice I forgot to specify the encoding, which I now added. :P