# Writing binary data in python (header fail)

Tags: python, c#, io, binary

I am trying to write a binary file in python. Usually, i use *numpy* and *struct.pack*.

I want to reproduce this header taken from a C# code:

```cpp
BinaryWriter writebin = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(..., FileMode.Create))
// write first Line = -99 +chr(13) +chr(10)
writebin.Write((byte)45);
writebin.Write((byte)57);
writebin.Write((byte)57);
writebin.Write((byte)32);
writebin.Write((byte)13);
writebin.Write((byte)10);
```

The opposite reading code in C# is:

First step, determine if it's binary:

```cpp
string[] text = new string[1];
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(..)
text = reader.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '\r', '\n' }, stringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (Convert.ToDouble(text[0]) < 0) {
  // THEN IT SHOULD GO ON
}
```

The second step would be something like:

```cpp
BinaryReader readbin = new BinaryReader(..))
// read 1st line inclusive carriage return and line feed
byte[] header;
header = readbin.ReadBytes(6);
```

Would you know how to do this in python. I just cannot get to write the header!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Binary data can be anything so using ReadLine and splitting make absolutely no sense.  Besides ReadLine will remove the return characters so splitting will not work.  A lot if binary files have an ascii header which ends with SOH.  So what you can do is use ReadAllBytes in to a byte[].  Then use Array.Find()  to look for the SOH.  Then you can extract the ascii header into a byte[] and use Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte[]) to get the header.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. My question was more how to write the file in python. In C#, everything works fine. But would like to write the same file using python. 
I tried:
import struct
with open(fname, mode='w') as fout:  
    fout.write("-99\r\n")
    
with open(fname, mode='wb+') as writebin: 
    writebin.write(struct.pack('i', nx))

but the C# code still chokes on Convert.ToDouble(text[0]) < 0 with a System.FormatException "Input was not in a correct format".

Comment: If you have binary you need to use wb in the open for both read and write.  You laso need to write bytes (not strings) so "-99\r\n" does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it! I feel pretty stupid...

```py
with open(str(filename), 'wb') as writebin:  
    writebin.write(struct.pack("=B",45))
    writebin.write(struct.pack("=B",57))
    writebin.write(struct.pack("=B",57))
    writebin.write(struct.pack("=B",32))
    writebin.write(struct.pack("=B",12))
    writebin.write(struct.pack("=B",10))    
    writebin.write(struct.pack('i', self.nx))
```

See old [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364905/how-to-write-1-byte-to-a-binary-file) ...